# 401 error creating MongoDB Cluster - You are not authorized for this resource

Tags: mongodb, azure, api, api-key, atlas

I get the error message in the title when I try to create a cluster with Terraform.
I am using API keys to proceed.
I whitelisted the IP address and added the ACL to the API key.
I ma owner of the project and the organization.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason: I was using an old version of the terraform code:

```
provider "mongodbatlas" {
  alias       = "mongo_db"
  public_key  = var.public_key
  private_key = var.private_key
}
```

But the new version doesn't include the alias line and it fixed the issue when I removed it.

```
provider "mongodbatlas" {
  public_key  = var.public_key
  private_key = var.private_key
}
```

Comment: Probably you were missing the `provider` attribute inside your resources. Setting an alias in your provider block allows you to use it in specific block resources when you more than one provider configured https://www.terraform.io/language/providers/configuration#alias-multiple-provider-configurations.